# Will TypeORM @AfterRemove or @BeforeRemove entity listeners still run when the db is dropped?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Some entities in my database have a property which is their associated key on AWS S3, for example:

```
// my.entity.ts
@Column()
s3Key: string;
```

I would like one of TypeOrm's [entity listeners](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/listeners-and-subscribers.md#beforeremove), `@AfterRemove` or `@BeforeRemove` to execute their functions when the table is dropped using the [TypeOrm cli](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/using-cli.md#drop-database-schema)? This kind of action would be really helpful when developing locally so I don't have to delete S3 objects one by one when dropping the db

```
// my.entity.ts
@AfterRemove()
async deleteFromS3AfterRemove() {
  await deleteFromS3("BUCKET_NAME", this.s3Key);
}
```

So, will these entity listeners still be executed when the table is dropped or does anyone know if `typeorm schema:drop` emits the remove subscription events?

I had a look around at the source and docs but couldn't find anything
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/commands/SchemaDropCommand.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work - entity listeners are not executed when dropping a database.

I span up a test database with some fake entities to test this out and I added the method

```
  @AfterRemove()
  async logIfWorking() {
    console.log('✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅');
  }
```

No console logs were seen when executing the schema drop command from the TypeORM cli